# Beku and bekarazu, I don't get how the zu form even become like that or am I thinking of two different verbs?

Tags: grammar, negation

I was looking at a website for beku and bekarazu, however, I think bekarazu is the zu form of beku and it just doesn't make sense. I would make it べかず　instead of べからず because it appeared on a website that the zu form is just the negative form, but instead of nai, zu is attached to the verb. Can someone answer my confusion?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/22953/9831 Also see: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18646/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

べく is the adverbial form of べし, which is, as a 形容詞, also regularised to べい dialectally. べからず simply consists of べく＋あらず, the latter being the verb in use, ある, in its classical negation. Compare and contrast to modern past positive ～かった, which is itself ～くありたり.

Comment: If you really want to break it down into historical components, ～かった is from ～く + ありて + あり.  However, this is not so useful for modern speakers to know.  :)  Colloquially / in modern usage, ～かった can also be analyzed as ～く + あった.