# Other types of adjectives (besides い and な)

Tags: adjectives, i-adjectives, na-adjectives

I recently started learning Japanese in my home country.
Last lesson we learned about the 2 types of adjectives, い and な.

Are there other types , like rare ones ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_equivalents_of_adjectives

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Japanese have two kinds of adjectives? (-i adjectives and -na adjectives)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1008/why-does-japanese-have-two-kinds-of-adjectives-i-adjectives-and-na-adjective)

Answer (score 2):

Na-adjectives and i-adjectives are the most common. There are also [no-adjectives](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2770/5010) (although they are just nouns from the standpoint of Japanese people). And there are also rare [archaic forms](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68109/5010), which may be encountered when you have reached advanced level and start reading literary works.